# How to loop different csv and merge them?

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a series of csv i need to grab from a url, they have different namings but the same extention .csv and the same exact format.

***Then convert it to json.***

The following is what i use for one but how to loop for any .csv?

Also once downloaded them how to merge them? So let's say we have different dates, we should expect a merge like:

```
 {
    "date": 2/4/20,
    "state": "AK",...
},
 {
    "date": 3/4/20,
    "state": "AK"...
```

This is the php I am using for a single csv

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (($handle = fopen("example.com/NAME.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $csvs = [];
    while(! feof($handle)) {
        $csvs[] = fgetcsv($handle);
    }
    $datas = [];
    $column_names = [];
    foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
        $column_names[] = $single_csv;
    }
    foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
        if ($key === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
            $datas[$key-1][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    fclose($handle);
    print_r($json);
}
```

What if we have

```
example.com/NAME.csv

example.com/NAME2.csv

example.com/NAME3.csv
```

**UPDATE**

[This is the series of csv and its data](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213291/discussion-on-question-by-rob-m-how-to-loop-different-csv-and-merge-them).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there is not a way (as I know) to just **scrape** a site and find all files with the same extension (as per comments said and as I could not find how to using php), I ended up creating an array of names (in my case are dates) and then loop it, then the output will be a merged json:

```
$arr = array("04-12-2020",
    "04-13-2020",
    "04-14-2020",
    "04-15-2020",
    "04-16-2020",
    "04-17-2020",
    "04-18-2020",
    "04-19-2020",
    "04-20-2020",
    "04-21-2020",
    "04-22-2020",
    "04-23-2020",
    "04-24-2020",
    "04-25-2020",
    "04-26-2020",
    "04-27-2020",
    "04-28-2020",
    "04-29-2020",
    "04-30-2020",
    "05-01-2020",
    "05-02-2020",
    "05-03-2020",
    "05-04-2020",
    "05-05-2020"
);

foreach($arr as $date) {
    $url = $url.$date.".csv";..
    // here the rest of the code as per the question
```

Not sure if this is the best way but works.

The result is a mega json with all dates and merged data as a single obj

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how does this connect to your question? How does a list of strings help to merge CSV files?

Comment: @NicoHaase it appends the csv converted to json as it downloads it

Comment: @NicoHaase also why a list of strings? It's a list of file names which I look and I attach the extension and then I loop running the code on the question. And why did you vote for my answer with a down vote placing it to zero?

Comment: @NicoHaase hi, have you asked to this user what has he tried? Are you going to down vote it?Just out of curiosity.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648962/how-to-turn-off-if-the-mobile-navbar-is-open-when-the-page-is-scrolled

Comment: No, why should I?

Comment: @NicoHaase well since that is what you have told me, while I actually put quite a lot of effort in trying my code, writing a proper question and also providing an answer. I am wondering if you'd do it for that question too where there is nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I've asked very kind how writing an array of strings solved your problem. Your initial question contained more requirements like merging data, and it's not that obvious to me how that line of strings helps to merge your data

Comment: Isn't it? If you dump `$arr`, what else does it contain if not a list of strings?

Comment: @NicoHaase I will get a list of file names as they are on the page I need to download as per the question.